# Pipes leading to "argument is not interpretable as logical" error?

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm encountering a bit of an error I can't explain, I've got a bs_carousel using the bsplus library.
A working version of it is of this pattern:

```
bs_carousel("info") %>% bs_set_data(interval = FALSE) %>% 
  bs_append(bs_carousel_image(image1, if(checker1 == 1){reactable(df1[,!(names(df1) %in% c("Day"))])}))%>% 
  bs_append(bs_carousel_image(image2, if(checker2 == 1){reactable(df2[,!(names(df2) %in% c("Day"))])}))%>% 
  bs_append(bs_carousel_image(image3, if(checker3 == 1){reactable(df3[,!(names(df3) %in% c("Day"))])}))
```

However I need to put another condition in that shows each "bs_append" when a condition is met:

```
bs_carousel("info") %>% bs_set_data(interval = FALSE) %>% 
      if(dim(df1_checked)[1] != 0){bs_append(bs_carousel_image(image1, if(checker1 == 1){reactable(df1[,!(names(df1) %in% c("Day"))])}))}%>% 
      if(dim(df2_checked)[1] != 0){bs_append(bs_carousel_image(image2, if(checker2 == 1){reactable(df2[,!(names(df2) %in% c("Day"))])}))}%>% 
      if(dim(df3_checked)[1] != 0){bs_append(bs_carousel_image(image3, if(checker3 == 1){reactable(df3[,!(names(df3) %in% c("Day"))])}))}
```

However for some reason, I get the following error:

```
Error in if (.) dim(df1_checked)[1] != 0 else { : 
  argument is not interpretable as logical
```

I don't think it's a data issue (therefore I haven't posted it yet), because when I put the entire bs_carousel in the same condition, it runs fine (or at least correctly for that conidition):

```
if(dim(df1_checked)[1] != 0){
bs_carousel("info") %>% bs_set_data(interval = FALSE) %>% 
  bs_append(bs_carousel_image(image1, if(checker1 == 1){reactable(df1[,!(names(df1) %in% c("Day"))])}))%>% 
  bs_append(bs_carousel_image(image2, if(checker2 == 1){reactable(df2[,!(names(df2) %in% c("Day"))])}))%>% 
  bs_append(bs_carousel_image(image3, if(checker3 == 1){reactable(df3[,!(names(df3) %in% c("Day"))])}))}
```

Is my syntax wrong, or am I missing something more fundamental?

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page on how to ask a question.  In particular code posted should be complete including all inputs (using `dput`) and library statements so others can copy and paste it into their session to run it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will get your end goal, but specific to your error message -- I believe this statement doesn't work because it's expecting an action after your "if" condition.

Try rewriting your logic in "if (.) dim(df1_checked)[1] != 0 else { :" to look like this psuedocode:

```
if (.) dim(df1_checked)[1] != 0{
    <do stuff>}
else {
    <do other stuff> }
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at this; unfortunately that leads to an error saying: "unexpected '{' in:
"bs_carousel("info") %>% bs_set_data(interval = FALSE) %>% 
  if (.) dim(df1_checked)[1] != 0{"

Comment: Bummer! Hope you figure it out - that was my only idea